# расстояние между айтемами recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, recyclerview, android-xml

Требуется при использовании `RecyclerView` не использовать `CardView`, тем самым корневой элемент становится `LinearLayout` и необходимое расстояние между элементами пропало.

Скрин №1:

[image]

Наглядно о том, что именно пропало.
Скрин №2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот и разметочка подъехала:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumpup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/thumbupgrey" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/likes"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="likes" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumpdown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/thumbdowngrey" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id="@+id/mainwords"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            аndroid:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/info"
            android:id="@+id/infobtn" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Каким образом снизу добавить линию для разделения итемов?

Пытался следующим образом, но холдер выплюнул эксепшеном в лицо:

```
<item>

    <shape android:shape="line">

        <stroke android:layout_width="match_parent" android:color="#F20107" />

    </shape>

</item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно создать наследника `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` и в нём задать нужные отступы:

```
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration
{
    private int space;

    public SpacesItemDecoration(int space)
    {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state)
    {
        //добавить переданное кол-во пикселей отступа снизу
        outRect.bottom = space;
    }
}
```

Потом, при инициализации `RecyclerView` присвоить его:

```
RecyclerView rv = ...;
rv.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(100));
```

Comment: или можно просто сделать фон для айтема с "тенью" снизу, как это сделано в `CardView`